# How to get the Version Number of Microsoft Office from its Build number in Powershell

Tags: powershell, office365, webrequest

I read on my Windows based systems (via Remote Powershell) what is installed on their computers.
 This creates a report. I am having some difficulties looking into the evaluation of the Microsoft Office software.

It is not hard to get the Office version from registry:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration' `
          | Select-Object -ExpandProperty VersionToReport
```

This will output to something like `16.0.14527.20276`.
It is also not hard to evaluate which main version this is:

| Nr | Office Version |
| --- | --- |
| 11.0 | Office 2003 |
| 12.0 | Office 2007 |
| 14.0 | Office 2010 |
| 15.0 | Office 2013 |
| 16.0 | Office 2016+ (2019 or 2022 or MS365 version) |

As you can see, the 16.0 version is kind of a collection of all latest Office variants. 
As logically as it might be to Microsoft, it is useless for my case.

The solution lies within the rest of the build number. These numbers specify which version of Office you have. 
Clearly we are using Office 365, but I want to know whether they are all up-to-date.

With the rest of the build number, you can get that finer grain of the version. 
You could look them up at this [Microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-microsoft365-apps-by-date#version-history). There you can find for instance that Build 14527.20234 is Version 2110.

Since I am monitoring hundreds of computers, this needs to be automated. 
So that everytime Microsoft creates a new version, it gets updated automatically.

How can I end up with an **up-to-date array with** both the **Build numbers and** the **Version numbers**?

Comment: Cast the version you get from the registry to `[Version]`. Then you can single out the Major, Minor, Build and Revision numbers. I.e: `[version]'16.0.14527.20276'` --> .Major -> 16, .Minor -> 0, .Build -> 14527 and .Revision -> 20276

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. That is okay-ish, but I want it in a human-readable form. Ie. with the YYMM version system from Microsoft. In that way I know how up-to-date (or not) a device is. '16.0.AAAA.BBBB' is pretty unreadable to me. I don't know all these versions by heart :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a function so you can call it as many times as you need.

It will only run if it needs to OR if you force it to (parameters `-ForceCSV` or `-Output`).
I added this to prevent the script starting the lookup everytime when you -for example- are polling 50 computers at the same time. The evaluation part prevents that, but can be overriden with the two mentioned parameters.

The CSV output then can be evaluated on other systems without the need of installing or pushing this function.
To keep the answer as short as possible, I removed as much `Write-Verbose` and comment lines as possible.

```
function Get-OfficeVersion {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([switch]$Output,[switch]$ForceCSV)

    $URL = "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-microsoft365-apps-by-date#version-history"
    $CsvFile = "\\server\share\OfficeVersions.csv"
    # Evaluate whether script should run
    if ( ((gci $CsvFile).LastWriteTime.Date -eq (Get-Date).Date) -and !($ForceCSV.IsPresent)) 
     {$CsvOutput = $false} else {$CsvOutput = $true}
    if ($Output.IsPresent -or $CsvOutput -or $ForceCSV.IsPresent) {
    #End Evaluation
        $VersionsSite = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL)
        $VersionTableRawData = ($VersionsSite.AllElements | Where-Object {$_.tagname -eq 'TD'}).innertext | ? {$_ -like "Version* (Build *)"}

        $Versions = @() 
        foreach ($DataItem in $VersionTableRawData) {
                $ProcessedItem = (($DataItem -replace "\)") -split "\s\(")

                $item = New-Object PSObject
                $item | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'Version'  -Value ([string]($ProcessedItem[0].ToString().split(' ')[1] -replace ' ' -replace 'Version' -replace 'Build' -replace "\n" -join ''))
                $item | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'Build'    -Value ([string]($ProcessedItem[1].ToString().split(' ')[1] -replace ' ' -replace 'Version' -replace 'Build' -replace "\n" -join ''))
                $Versions += $item
        }

        $VersionsSorted = $Versions | sort Build -Unique | sort Version -Descending | select Build,Version
        if ($Output.IsPresent) {return $VersionsSorted}
    
        If ($CsvOutput) {$VersionsSorted | Export-csv -Path $CsvFile -Force -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ','}
    }
}
```

As a bonus, I also do the evaluation part of this list.
First you get the Office Version:

```
$OfficeVersionX32        = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty VersionToReport
$OfficeVersionX64        = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue)
if ( $OfficeVersionX32 -ne $null -and $OfficeVersionX64 -ne $null) {
  $OfficeVersion = "Both x32 version ($OfficeVersionX32) and x64 version ($OfficeVersionX64) installed!"
} elseif ($OfficeVersionX32 -eq $null -or $OfficeVersionX64 -eq $null) {
  $OfficeVersion = $OfficeVersionX32 + $OfficeVersionX64
}
$OfficeVersionMain = $OfficeVersion.Split(".")[0]
$OfficeVersionSub1  = $OfficeVersion.ToString().Replace("16.0.","")
```

Which you then can use to evaluate the system.
As told, for version numbers 11.0 untill 15.0 it is easy, the difficulties start at version 16.0.

```
$CsvFile = "\\server\share\OfficeVersions.csv"
Switch  ($OfficeVersionMain) {
    11      {$MSOffice ="Office 2003 ($OfficeVersion)" }
    12      {$MSOffice ="Office 2007 ($OfficeVersion)" }
    14      {$MSOffice ="Office 2010 ($OfficeVersion)" }
    15      {$MSOffice ="Office 2013 ($OfficeVersion)" }
    16      {
                $LatestOfficeVersions = Import-Csv $CsvFile
                $MSOffice = "Office 365 (Version $(($LatestOfficeVersions | ? {$_.Build -eq $OfficeVersionSub1}).Version), $OfficeVersionSub1)"
            }
    default {$MSOffice = $OfficeVersion}
    $null   {$MSOffice = "No Office installed."}
}
```

And with the output `$MSOffice` you can continue.
It should be of the form `"Office 365 (Version 2110, 14527.20234)"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could check https://config.office.com/officeSettings/inventory and have an overview in the Microsoft 365 Apps Admin Center. This would be the Microsoft Cloudway of seeing all your Office365 Installations and should work out of the box (no scripting or configuration needed). You can check the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/admincenter/inventory or see the techcomunity articel here https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-blog/inventory-on-microsoft-365-apps-admin-center-goes-ga/ba-p/2500065 . This is not the way to update all of your installations, but to see every installation and export this via csv and use it in a script to update. I hope this helps someone. [Picture of Inventory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v69CS.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).